# need to check birthdate in Validation rule

Tags: validation, validation-rule

I need to check birthdate in validation rule .If birthdate==01/01/2000 then i need to throw an validation error.

I used below condition but I am getting different error
***Birthdate=DATE(01,01,2000)***

Error while saving record:

> Validation Formula "birtdate_Validation" Invalid (Month or Day out of range in DATE() function)'

Comment: Please do not remove your entire question body once you receive an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Date function takes Year, Month and Date in that order.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions_a_h.htm&type=5

eg.

```
DATE(2000, 01, 01)
```